# gcc builds with -o but not -o3?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-optimization

My Makefile looks like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic
OBJECTS=main.o Scene.o Matrix.o Vector.o Triangle.o Color.o Raster.o

render: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -lm -o render -g $(OBJECTS)
    rm $(OBJECTS)

clean:
    rm -f render*
```

This builds my executable with no errors, but when I change -o to -o2 or -o3, I get the error:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic   -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic   -c -o Scene.o Scene.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic   -c -o Matrix.o Matrix.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic   -c -o Vector.o Vector.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic   -c -o Triangle.o Triangle.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic   -c -o Color.o Color.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic   -c -o Raster.o Raster.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic -lm -o3 render -g main.o Scene.o Matrix.o Vector.o Triangle.o Color.o Raster.o
gcc.exe: error: render: No such file or directory
make: *** [render] Error 1
```

There could be some error in my code detected by the optimization flags, but as I don't get any error messages before this it's hard to know what's going wrong. I'm using MinGW/MSYS on Windows 7.

Comment: `-O` (capital) for optimizer settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-o render` means create the output file with the name `render`.

Now you are changing this `-o` to `-o3` which is incorrect. Instead you need to keep `-o render` as it is and add a `-O3` flag for optimization. Note the capital letter `O`.

Comment: beside the fact that trying to link time optimize objects that were compiled without optimization is almost pointless (the -o name does the same thing as -c name.c).  Just replace -o name with -O2 or -Os or -O3 if you want actual optimization  This is another example of case insensitivity tripping up experienced windows users... btw C is case sensitive too :p -brad (my name is case insensitive ;))

Answer (score 4):

`-o` is the output file flag. You were thinking of `-O` (capital).